# C++: Convert multiple command line arguments from a single std::stringstream

Tags: c++, c++17, command-line-arguments, stringstream

I have a program which inputs multiple string and numeric variables from the command line. As I want to convert few inputs to numeric types, I have been using `std::stringstream` as suggested at [learncpp](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/713-command-line-arguments/). Presently, my code looks something like:

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
if (argc != 7)
{
     std::cout << "Execute the program in the following format:\n";
     std::cout << ".\segment inputImage outputDir color k sigma minSize\n";
     std::cout << "Exiting program\n";
     std::exit(1);
}

float gaussianBlur, kValue;
int minimumComponentSize;
std::filesystem::path path = std::filesystem::u8path(argv[1]);
std::string outputFolder = argv[2];
std::string color = argv[3];

std::stringstream convert{argv[4]};
if (!(convert >> gaussianBlur))
{
     gaussianBlur = 1.5; // default value
}

std::stringstream convertK{argv[5]};
if (!(convertK >> kValue))
{
     kValue = 900; // default value
}

std::stringstream convertMin{argv[6]};
if (!(convertMin >> minimumComponentSize))
{
     minimumComponentSize = 900;
}
 ....
```

As you can see, I'm creating a `stringstream` variable for each argument that I want to convert to a numeric type.  I can't re-assign another value to `stringstream` variables. Is there a way to convert all the arguments from a single `stringstream`? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the required `argv` values into a single `stringstream` (separated by spaces), then read each out into the corresponding variables:

```cpp
//...
std::stringstream convert;
convert << argv[4] << " " << argv[5] << " " argv[6]; // Add more "argv" strings
convert >> gaussianBlur >> kValue >> minimumComponentSize; // Read more values
//...
```

But, of course, error conditions are then a bit trickier to check for; if you *need* this, you can read the items from that (single) `stringstream` one at a time, as you already do:

```cpp
if (!(convert >> gaussianBlur))
{
    gaussianBlur = 1.5; // default value
}
if (!(convert >> kValue))
{
    kValue = 900; // default value
}
if (!(convert >> minimumComponentSize))
{
    minimumComponentSize = 900;
}
```

Comment: Please don’t suggest concatenating `argv`, undoing whatever careful work in quoting and separating arguments.  In this trivial case it might not matter, but it’s a bad example to set.

Answer (score 1):

To reassign a different value to the same `std::stringstream` you'll need to clear it:

```
convert.str(std::string());
```

Now it's clerared an you can reuse it with a different value.

You must also call `convert.clear();` to reset all the previously seted flags.

To add all the arguments to the same `std::stringstream` [@AdrianMole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62386046/6865932).